# How to solve issue with React build

Tags: reactjs, npm, iis

After making changes to the react application. I want to build the changes again and redeploy to IIS. but for a strange reason, the build is not working again. I have tried everything to rebuild but non has worked.

I tried

```
npm run build:prod
```

```
> project@0.1.0 build:prod C:\Users\MYNAME\source\repos\Project
> env-cmd -f .env.prod npm run build

npm ERR! missing script: build

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\MYNAME\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-04-19T13_38_22_516Z-debug.log
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! Project@0.1.0 build:prod: `env-cmd -f .env.prod npm run build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the Project@0.1.0 build:prod script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
```

Here is the script part of my package.json

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "env-cmd -f .env.dev react-scripts start",
    "build:prod": "env-cmd -f .env.prod npm run build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `"build:prod": "env-cmd -f .env.prod npm run build"` the `npm run build` is missing. You have only `start`,  `build:prod`, `test`, `eject` scripts, and no `build` exists.

Comment: This is what I got when I tried ```npm build:prod``` I got ```Specify configs in the ini-formatted file:
    C:\Users\MYNAME\.npmrc
or on the command line via: npm <command> --key value
Config info can be viewed via: npm help config

npm@6.14.11 C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm```

Comment: Maybe you accidentally removed `build:react-scripts build` from your `package.json`.

Comment: Yes, while trying to solve the issue of env for working on IIS server. I was trying different stuff, I removed the ```build:react-scripts build``` hopefully the env file will work on the server now